# Specify which match to keep in List.Intersect

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to find the intersection between two lists using the Linq Intersect method and a custom equality provider.

The lists contain objects (representing a file system file) and contain relative and absolute paths.  I have defined a IEqualityComparer class to declare two files as equal if they have the same *relative path*.

I now would like to specify in the Intersect method that the match with more recent modify date is the one to keep in the resulting intersection list.

What is the best way to do this?  Can I modify the IEqualityComparer to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not understanding it correctly. `Intersect` means that the objects are equal and just after you say "oh no they are not equal". Intersect is not the function you want. You want something like `GroupBy` instead. Leave `Intersect` alone until you really need an intersection.

Comment: I don't think group by is the kind of logic I want because I want to return a subset of the total list.  If intersect is not the correct method, fine, then what is the way to identify objects from different lists that match on a specific property with secondary filtering?  Are you saying this isnt something that can be done with linq?

Comment: It's a common problem we encountered in our enterprise. Usually I suggest things to join the list, group by the key and select only the elements that contains two items (I refuse that my coworkers use a method they don't really understand).